# Ring of differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is this true that if $A$ and $B$ are $R$-algebras, where $R$ is a commutative ring, then
$$\Omega^1_{A \otimes_R B/ R} \simeq A \otimes_R \Omega^1_{B/R} \oplus B \otimes_R \Omega^1_{A/R}.$$
If it is true I struggle to prove it.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652051/k%C3%A4hler-differentials-of-tensor-product).

Comment: Thanks you very much